# Blowfish Implementation for C#.NET - Moving from PHP to C#

Tags: c#, php, cryptography, blowfish

I'm moving my application from PHP to C# MVC.  I've been using the following method to encrypt passwords:

```
string password_hash ( string $password )
```

By Default, password_hash() uses the BLOWFISH hashing algorithm and produces hashes prefixed with `$2y$`.

I've looked at, and given a go, quite a few *supposed* implementations of the algorithm, but none of them seem to work with my existing hashes and I'm not sure if I can trust any of them.

I've tried:

- **Bcrypt.NET from Nuget**
- [This](https://defuse.ca/blowfish.htm)
- I was thinking of giving [This](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/) a go until I realised that it says 'Unlisted' on the Nuget page.

I need it so that I can verify existing hashes in my database and restore them using the standard C# .MVC Identity Framework method when a user logs in again.

How can I verify passwords generated using `password_hash()` in PHP using C#?

Comment: I have amended my question, describing the problem and requesting a solution.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks for retracting the close vote... oh wait!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just stumbled upon a package called `CryptSharp` which appears to verify passwords similarly to the way that `password_verify()` in PHP would.  I have tested it on a few existing password hashes produced by PHP...

```
using CryptSharp;
bool matches = Crypter.CheckPassword("password", "password hash");
```

Here's the [Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CryptSharpOfficial/) and [Docs](http://www.zer7.com/software/cryptsharp)

I used version 2.0.0...

Comment: I hope this helps some fellow PHP to C# Converts :)